# python discord bot sleep to stop people spamming

Tags: python, time, async-await, discord

when trying the make the bot sleep for 5 seconds before it replies again. but i can continue spamming "down" and bot replies

```
import os
import random
import discord
import time 

keywords3 = ['down']

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
global cooldown

if message.author == client.user:
    return

 messC = message.content.lower()

if any(word in messC for word in keywords3):
    await message.channel.send('hello')
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
```

`

Answer (score 0):

i'm not familiar with the discord api but this should do what you want

```py
cooling_down = False
eventually_cool_up_task = None

async def eventually_cool_up(wait):
    global cooling_down

    await asyncio.sleep(wait)
    cooling_down = False

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    global cooling_down, eventually_cool_up_task

    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    messC = message.content.lower()

    if any(word in messC for word in keywords3):
        if not cooling_down:
            cooling_down = True
            await message.channel.send('hello')
            eventually_cool_up_task = asyncio.create_task(eventually_cool_up(5))
```